# Javascript function order execution and good practise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why this work

```
$("#tag-search").autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        source: tags,
        messages: {
            noResult: '',
            results: function () {}
        },
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $('.tags').append('<span class="tag-style">' + ui.item.value + '<i class="fa fa-times tag-del" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');
            ui.item.value = "";
            $('.tag-del').click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        }
    });
```

and this no?

```
$("#tag-search").autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        source: tags,
        messages: {
            noResult: '',
            results: function () {}
        },
        select: function (e, ui) {
            $('.tags').append('<span class="tag-style">' + ui.item.value + '<i class="fa fa-times tag-del" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');
            ui.item.value = "";
        }
    });

    $('.tag-del').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

I have never understood how javascript is compiled and how work functions! Someone can help me?
And last thing: is better write javascript in body page or in a external file? If i should write in external file how can send php response to javascript file? Thanks!

Comment: It's not about compiling is about synchrony `autocomplete` is asynchronous (gets executed in the background while the rest of script keeps running), so your `click` event can't be added to `.tag-del`  element since it doesn't exist until `select: function` is called in your autocomplete function.

Comment: The problem is because, in the second example, `.tag-del` does not exist in the DOM when you attempt to bind an event handler to it. You can instead bind the handler at the point you create the element - which is what your first example is doing - or better yet, you can use a single delegated event handler on a parent element. See the duplicate I marked for how to do that